# Function to ignore nan values and do a numpy.polyval

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, iteration, nan

I am trying to code a function where you feed it an mxn array, the goal of it is to iterate through the array and execute numpy.polyval for each value. The arrays will contain some nan values so I want the function to return the nan value in the same order as it was on the original array.
Here is my function so far:

```
def polyval_NaN(p,data):
    m,n = data.shape
    data2 = data
    for i in np.arange(1,m):
        for j in np.arange(1,n):
            if np.isnan(data2[i,j]) == False:
                data2[i,j] = np.polyval(p,data[i,j])
    return data2
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use boolean indexing like so:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> p = np.array((4,5,3))
>>> a = np.arange(12.).reshape(3,4)
>>> a.ravel()[[2,5,7]] = np.nan
>>> a
array([[ 0.,  1., nan,  3.],
       [ 4., nan,  6., nan],
       [ 8.,  9., 10., 11.]])
>>> 
>>> result = np.full_like(a, np.nan)
>>> good = ~np.isnan(a)
>>> result[good] = np.polyval(p, a[good])
>>> 
>>> result
array([[  3.,  12.,  nan,  54.],
       [ 87.,  nan, 177.,  nan],
       [299., 372., 453., 542.]])
```

Comment: how would I incorporate this in my function, I am trying to generalize it and not just do a particular case

Comment: @Heavens93 C'mon you can work that out yourself. It's literally as simple as choosing a name, indenting, and adding a return statement,

Comment: this does not work with a polyval with degree 1 i.e. p=1

Comment: @Heavens93 try `p=[1]`.